# System.Byte in datagrid column

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid

I am using the following query:

```
string query = @"SELECT r.id, user_name, user_phone, date_create, REPLACE( date_payment,  '0000-00-00 00:00:00',  'Не оплачено' ) as 
                date_payment, payment_method, amount, rs.name_ru
                FROM request AS r, request_status AS rs
                WHERE r.status = rs.id";
```

And i am binding datatemplate in the following way:

```
DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding date_payment}" Width="135" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Its throwing correct output except the "**date_payment**" Its output value comes "**System.Byte[]**".
please help!!!

**Thank from MBen**

```
class ByteArrayToString : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                var listOfBytes = value as Byte[];
                string output = "";
                output = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(listOfBytes);
                return output;
            }

            return "";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `date_payment` ? seems like Date and why does it need to be `byte[]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date_payment`  is an Array, and you didn't provide any way for WPF for displaying it, so it calls `ToString` . You can provide a data converter for it.

Add a resource to your Window or page :

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <local:ByteArrayToString x:Key="ByteArrayConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
```

Use it in your `TextBlock` as such :

```
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding date_payement, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayConverter}}" Width="135" />
```

Now you need to add a new class that does the conversion :

```
    class ByteArrayToString : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                var listOfBytes = value as Byte[];
                string output ="";
                output = listOfBytes.Aggregate(output, (current, elemt) => current + elemt.ToString());
                return output;
            }

            return "";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: two seconds :). writing it up

Comment: local is just namepsace where I defined the ValueConverter :  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5". If you notice I named the class ByteArrayToString in the C# code I pasted

Comment: i get in column integer, so "28347563728282"... pleae help :))))))))

Comment: you need to change the converter the display the Bytes as you want. The one I gave you just concatenates everything. Change this line `output = listOfBytes.Aggregate(output, (current, elemt) => current + elemt.ToString());` to format it the way you want.

Comment: i change `output = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(listOfBytes);` and she works!!!!!! thank so very very very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

This thing happened to me to. It seems this is due to a bug in the connector. Try to cast the date column to CHAR. It worked for me.